# Why does my attempt at RSA break?

Tags: rsa

I have that $N = 798$, $p=2$, and $q=399$. I choose $e$ such that $\gcd(e,(p-1)(q-1))=1$ where $e=7$. I, then, choose $m = 123$. Thus, $c=123^{7}\bmod798=669$, which is my ciphertext. After, I try $d=7^{-1}\bmod398=57$. I, then, get the wrong result that $m'=669^{57}\bmod798=729$ which is not my original message $m$.

Why is this? I can't seem to understand why RSA would break. Does RSA break if either $p$ or $q$ is 2 and the other is a composite?

Comment: I edited the question to use the correct formulas for RSA encryption and decryption. That's _not_ $c\equiv m^e\pmod N$ (meaning that $m^e-c$ is a multiple of $N$ ), because it does not uniquely define $c$, and for example allows $c=m^e$. We need $0\le c<N$, and the notation for that is $c=m^e\bmod N$, where $\bmod$ is an operator computing the remainder of the Euclidean division. As pointed in [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/56094/555), the issue in the question's calculations is that $q$ is composite, and $\varphi(p\,q)\ne(p-1)(q-1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your q is composite with factors 3,7,19 we get $\phi(q)=(3-1)*(7-1)*(19-1)=216$ and not 398 The rest of the calculation follow as in the question.

And since $p=2$ we get also $\phi(n) = 216$

As a result we also get $d=e^{-1}=7^{-1}=31 \bmod 216$

And we can verify that $669^{31} \bmod 798 =123$ as expected.

Comment: I see. So, when using RSA, $\phi$($q$) is only ($q$-1) when $q$ is prime. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, RSA is defined for $N$ being the product of two primes.

There  have been multi-prime RSA defined, for some other specific purposes,  but the decryption functions would be different since $\phi(N)\neq (p-1)(q-1)$
anymore if $q$ is composite. Let $N$ be a product of distinct primes $N=p_1\cdot p_2 \cdots p_m,$ then the correct Euler's totient is $$\phi(N)=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_m-1).$$

Comment: Does 2 being a factor have a special case for it, though? It seems like when I choose any other prime and composite (say $p = 11$ and $q=300$) it does not break it; only when it is 2 and a composite.

Comment: No, it has failed for me on the first experiment.

Comment: n:=11*300; "eulerphi", EulerPhi(n);
phi:=10*299;phi;"wrongphi", phi; 
e:=7; GCD(e,phi);
m:=101; "plaintext", m;
c:= m^7 mod phi; "ciphertext under wrong phi", c;
d:=Modinv(7,phi); "wrong decryption key", d; 
"decryption", c^d mod phi;
d:=Modinv(7,EulerPhi(n)); "correct d",d;
c:=m^7 mod EulerPhi(n); "correct ciphertext", c;
"decryption", c^d mod EulerPhi(n);                                                
 **this magma code gives**

Comment: eulerphi 800
2990
wrongphi 2990
1
plaintext 101
ciphertext 2051
wrong decryption key 2563
decryption 231
correct d 343
correct ciphertext 301
decryption 101